# Unable to share the Google Bigquery bucket and folders to the vendor

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created a BigQuery bucket and inside that bucket, I have created a folder. I want to share this folder with the vendor so that they can send the data in.

As of now, they are able to access the bucket but not the folder inside the bucket.
Can you please help what permissions I need to give so that they can load the data into the bucket (and the folder)

Thanks,
Radhika

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not a bigquery bucket but a Cloud Storage bucket. Then, in Cloud Storage, folder doesn't exist (all the file are stored at the bucket level, the `/` character is a human representation for folder and the UI display them like that, but they aren't a true existence, it's virtual (you can convince yourselves by creating a single file in the folder and then by deleting the file, the folder also disappear).

All of that to say that the folder doesn't exist and it's not a resource on which you can grant permissions (or ACL). The Bucket is the lower level of resources in CLoud Storage.

---

So the user need the storage.objectViewer or storage.objectCreator or storage.objectAdmin (to read and Write) roles to read or write object on Cloud Storage